# binascii.Error: Invaild base64-encoded string: number of data characters(1957) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to decode a string to base64, then decompress it to zlib, but this message came out:

> binascii.Error: Invaild base64-encoded string: number of data
> characters(1957) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4

Code:

```py
def decode_token(token):
    # token is a string
    token_decode = base64.b64decode(token.encode())
    token_string = zlib.decompress(token_decode)
    return token_string
```

Comment: Perhaps it would help others debug your issue if you provided a minimal reproduceable example, like in the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It also just seems like you have one more character in your token than needed, as the length seems to be incorrect (needs to be a multiple of 4)

Answer (score 2):

The error basically means that your base64 input is incorrect. The base64 encoding converts every 3 input bytes to 4 ASCII characters from a restricted set, but the data you passed in seems to decode to something which is not an even multiple of 3 bytes -- it's as if a 2/3 byte slipped in, and there is no way to decode that. Quite simply, your input is corrupted. (You can try to drop one character from the base64 and see if you manage to decode correctly, but then how do you know if the decoded data is correct, or just gibberish?)

Answer (score 1):

I've also got this error because of modifying a session cookie. When I accessed the django server(localhost:8000) via chrome, i got this error but then using incognito mode, it worked.

The solution was to clear my cookies. I hope that helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

I was sending a base64 audio file using json.

On the server received this data:

```
data:audio/webm;codecs=opus;base64,GkXfo59ChoEBQveBAULygQRC84EIQoKEd2VibUKH
gQRChYECGFOAZwH/////////FUmpZpkq17GDD0JATYCGQ2hyb21lV0GGQ2hyb21lFlSua7+uvde
BAXPFh92N22LbK2CDgQKGhkFfT1BVU2Oik09wdXNIZWFkAQEAAIC7AAAAAADhjbWERzuAAJ+BAW
JkgSAfQ7Z1Af/////////ngQCjQYaBAACA+4OtX338PBu4bnSDfneNZGIiUHyTxHm2rT3E/1TL9
cIOCOstqZXLLpCP+SCP02KLi/+szgCGgHJQONOc4x9WBImn0XDNhgIcAG4wpEAVLEr53fnM8Pcw
ouC5etV7QAcFxIJtdQbRLYZmSmFsMi41YIAoBe7+JTHVSfMOSsE2cEqejD4nkBeDj4kX9but6xE
LHo+6gG2HkYWmlG/c0nNb31DuhT+SA8Go+MRhlB7wfmg/p4kNjbpxFYJX3yOphnkBTxQyADZd8
71n1ddOWeNmBX8Ss9zShKP2pF3I8CCakBTQp4nXaDqO8oY0PVJJcs1sAwiEVgUG813MNCeP8K5
8IR9B980S8KfXO1AqZINNPy6YQA6M=
```

The base64 itself starts after:

```
data:audio/webm;codecs=opus;base64,
```

You may also have additional data.

Comment: this was my case as well

Answer (score 0):

### What is Base64?

[Base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) uses one byte of input data to represent up to 6 bits of output. It "wastes space" in order to ensure that every byte corresponds to a plain, printable ASCII symbol, using very limited punctuation. The idea is that this makes it very hard to corrupt the data accidentally (for example, by feeding raw binary to a communication protocol that uses the high bit of each byte for a special purpose) and easy to embed the data in other contexts (for example, to store binary data within a JSON document without worrying about any of that content being interpreted as part of the JSON markup - although this is serendipitous, as Base64 is much older than JSON).

### Why are there restrictions on the input length?

Every base64 input is supposed to represent a whole number of bytes of output. Each set of 4 bytes of input neatly encodes 24 bits, i.e., 3 bytes of output data.

If, after taking groups of 4 bytes from the input, there are 3 left over, these could represent up to 18 bits; 16 will be used to make two data bytes, and the last two are ignored. Similarly, if 2 are left over, 8 of the possible 12 bits will be used to make one byte of output. And of course, if there is nothing left over, there is no problem.

However, if there is a single input byte left, then it does not represent enough data to make an output bytes. The entire input is wasted. The specification does not permit this, so Python raises an error.

### Why was the data of such a length?

Clearly, if `token_decode = base64.b64decode(token.encode())` raises an error from the `base64.b64decode` part concerning the length of the data, then `token.encode` must have produced data of an invalid length.

Assuming that `token` is a string that represents valid Base64 data, each text character should end up translated to a single byte, so the length in bytes of `token.encode()` would match the length of `token` in characters; and if `token` is valid Base64 data, then it would have to be of the correct length. So, one of these assumptions must be violated.

That is to say, the string could not have been valid Base64 data. Some contexts allow a Base64 stream to contain characters not used by the Base64 encoding scheme, and simply discard them. Python's decoder, however, is strict. If this is the problem, fixing it is a simple matter of explicitly filtering out the invalid characters.

In a web context, it should be noted that a "data url" might be base64 data with some sort of prefix. The prefix needs to be discarded before decoding, as it may contain characters that are valid for base64 but not intended to be interpreted as such.

If the string happened to contain Unicode code points 128 and above, those could have additionally resulted in `token.encode()` having a different length from the original `token` (since UTF-8 is the default encoding). However, those characters would not have been valid anyway, so this does not give any particular insight into the problem.